# Least Squares Solution of Linear Algerbraic Equation Ax = By in Eigen C++

Tags: c++, linear-algebra, eigen

I have a set of linear algebraic equations in matrices form, **Ax=By**. Where **A** is matrix of `36x20` and **x** is a vector of size `20`, **B** is `36x13` and **y** is `13x1`. **Rank(A)=20**. Because system is overdetermined (there are more number of equations than the variables), so least squares solution is possible, i,e; **x = (A^TA)^-1A^TBy**. I want the solution so that the residual error e = Ax-By should be minimized.

Using `Eigen/Dense` library of C++ i have formulated all the matrices etc. I tried the method described on this page 
[Eigen Tutorial](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TutorialLinearAlgebra.html)!

I guess the method described in this page is only for square matrices. Because when it try to run this it gives error.

```
 x = A.jacobiSvd( ComputeThinU | ComputeThinV ).solve(B*y);
```

Error

```
 /usr/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/SVD/JacobiSVD.h: In member function 'const    
 Eigen::internal::solve_retval<Eigen::JacobiSVD<MatrixType, QRPreconditioner>, Rhs> 
 Eigen::JacobiSVD<MatrixType, QRPreconditioner>::solve(const 
 Eigen::MatrixBase<OtherDerived>&) const [with Rhs = 
 Eigen::GeneralProduct<Eigen::Matrix<float, 36, 13>, Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, 1>, 4>; 
 _MatrixType = Eigen::Matrix<float, 36, 20>; int QRPreconditioner = 2]':
 /usr/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/SVD/JacobiSVD.h:658:5: warning: control reaches end of  
 non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
 make[2]: *** [src/CMakeFiles/spacebot_actuationKinematics.dir 
 /ActuationKinematics.cpp.o] Error 1
 make[1]: *** [src/CMakeFiles/spacebot_actuationKinematics.dir/all] Error 2
 make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Comment: The page favors the QR decomposition. Did you try it? It also works with rectangular matrices A for least squares, as well as the SVD method. Your error is from a missing return statement in some special case of the reported function, check bug reports for Eigen.

Comment: what do you mean by y? LS method is to find parameters of linear combination of x that best fit x observed into y observed. So you substitute x values and y values to equation. Do you have 36 observations?

Comment: @LutzL Yes I tried it. Here is the output. Assertion failed because rows == cols.
ActuationKinematicsTest: /usr/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/LU/Inverse.h:334: const Eigen::internal::inverse_impl<Derived> Eigen::MatrixBase<Derived>::inverse() const [with Derived = Eigen::Matrix<double, 36, 20>]: Assertion `rows() == cols()' failed.
Aborted (core dumped)

Comment: Yes of course, that is to be expected if you try to compute the inverse matrix using the LU factorization. That is only possible for regular square matrices. Use QR as fast and SVD as slower but more stable factorization and do not compute inverse matrices, only solve linear systems.

Comment: @LutzL Ohh yes you are right. It was my mistake I was taking inverse just for troubleshooting purpose in main source file and i did not check. Thanks. QR does not give Ax - By = 0 always. There is a huge error. Because my Y is a variable vector coming from the sensors and A & B are not constant but also dependant on the sensor values. How could I minimize the error in each loop?

Comment: @LutzL QR is least accurate one.

Comment: This is a rather strong statement. If A has full rank and reasonable condition number, QR is numerically as stable as SVD. LU comes only close if full, expensive pivoting is employed. If the matrix A is rank deficient or nearly so, you will need SVD to decide on the effective rank. But any solution of a linear system will dramatically depend on the threshold were you decide if a singular value is only small or effectively zero.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that is having a problem with the matrix multiplication in your solve(B*y); part. Try doing B*y separately and use solve(result); instead.

```
Eigen::GeneralProduct<Eigen::Matrix<float, 36, 13>, Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, 1>, 4>
```

That line gave me this suspicion. It says that the y variable came with a size of -1x1, thus your program wont run no matter what since it can't multiply with the matrix.

Also, the tutorial says...

```
A.jacobiSvd(ComputeThinU | ComputeThinV).solve(b) << endl;
```

I don't know how Eigen works exactly, but that seems to be the problem.

Comment: if the order of matrix `B` is `m x n` and order of vector `y` is `p x q` then for multiplication `p == n` and in my case it is always true. What is the difference if we do multiplication outside or in the parameter container? There is no more problem in this line.  QR decomposition worked for my case but the solution of x is not precise. as my A,B any y are variable over time.

Comment: @wafeeq Depends on the method overloading, how it takes its arguments. Maybe it can't resolve the multiplication when done inside the parenthesis. I know that the matrices are right, looking at it from a programmer's perspective it seems that the second arg is not being handled correctly, just look at the debug information from gcc.The only way I will find out for sure is by investigating eigen deeper.

Answer (score 0):

As explained in the documentation, the `ComputeThin*` options are only for `Dynamic` sized matrices. For fixed sizes, you must use `ComputeFull*`. Nevertheless, in your case it is better to use `Dynamic` size matrices, i.e., `MatrixXf`. Fixed size matrices only makes sense for very small ones.

Finally, ColPivHouseholderQR is probably a better choice for least-square solving. SVD is a bit overkill.

Comment: I guess there is nothing to do with the matrices whether they are dynamically allocated memory or not. I have already used MatrixXd in my code. The problem is that the error of least square solution is not acceptable. its big. error = Ax-By after finding the value of x by least squares.