# Linear least square equation solving using c++ eigen library (dynamic allocation)

Tags: c++, linear-algebra, eigen

I am trying to solve a simple least square of type Ax = b. The c++ eigen library offers several functionalities regarding this and I have seen some kind of solutions here: [Solving system Ax=b in linear least squares fashion with complex elements and lower-triangular square A matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13747290/solving-system-ax-b-in-linear-least-squares-fashion-with-complex-elements-and-lo) and here: [Least Squares Solution of Linear Algerbraic Equation Ax = By in Eigen C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22101591/least-squares-solution-of-linear-algerbraic-equation-ax-by-in-eigen-c)
What I want to do is that using dynamic version of the matrix A and b. The elements of matrix A are floating points in my case and has 3 columns, but the number of data items (i.e. rows) will be dynamic (inside a loop).
It will be helpful to have a short code snippet of basic declaration of A, b and filling out values.

Comment: http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TutorialMatrixClass.html#title2

Comment: I cannot find the question.

Answer (score 1):

If you need dynamic matrices/vectors, just use:

```
MatrixXd m1(5,7); // double
VectorXd v1(23);  // double

MatrixXf m2(3,5); // floating
VectorXf v2(12);  // floating
```

Those variables will all be saved in heap.

If you need square matrices or vectors with fixed size (but be careful, they aren't dynamic!) use the following syntax:

```
Matrix3d m3; // double, size 3x3
Vector3d v3; // double, size 1x3

Matrix4d m4; // double, size 4x4
Vector4d v4; // double, size 1x4
```

Comment: Looks like that link has since been removed; can we get an update or copy paste?

Comment: Unfortunately, that was my old blogspot page the doesn't exist anymore. I'm sorry for that! I will edit the answer in order to remove the broken link.